# concat string values of two columns groupby the values of another column and delete the remaining rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following dataset:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Stay home', "Stay home","Stay home", 'Go outside', "Go Outside","Go outside"],
                    'Child' : ['Severe weather', "Severe weather", "Severe weather", 'Sunny', "Sunny", "Sunny"],
                    'Topic' : ['Stay home', "Close windows","Don't go outside", 'bysicle ride', "go outside", 'Play'],
                    'Score' : ['0.58', '0.58', '0.58', '0.41', '0.41', '0.41']})


      Parent    Child           Topic                     Score
0   Stay home   Severe weather  Stay home                 0.58
1   Stay home   Severe weather  Close windows             0.58
2   Stay home   Severe weather  Don't go outside          0.58
3   Go outside  Sunny           bysicle ride              0.41
4   Go Outside  Sunny           go outside                0.41
5   Go outside  Sunny           Play                      0.41
```

I want to `concat` the `Child` and `Topic` columns `groupby` the values of `Child` and delete the remaining `rows` and `columns`

**Expected outcome:**

```
    Parent            list1                                                             Score
0   Stay home   ['Severe weather', 'Stay home',    'Close windows', 'Don't go outside'] 0.58            
1   Go outside  ['Sunny',          'bysicle ride', 'go outside',    'Play']             0.41
```

I tried this but not get the desired outcome:

```
df1['list1']=  df1[~df1.duplicated(subset=['Child'], keep='first')
                 ]['Child'].map(df1.groupby('Child')['Topic'].apply(list) )

      Parent    Child           Topic               Score                  list1
0   Stay home   Severe weather  Stay home           0.58       [Stay home, Close windows, Don't go outside]
1   Stay home   Severe weather  Close windows       0.58       NaN
2   Stay home   Severe weather  Don't go outside    0.58       NaN
3   Go outside  Sunny           bysicle ride        0.41       [bysicle ride, go outside, Play]
4   Go Outside  Sunny           go outside          0.41       NaN
5   Go outside  Sunny           Play                0.41       NaN
```

Also I tried this:

```
df1 = df1.groupby('Child')['Topic'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()

    Child           Topic
0   Severe weather  Stay home,Close windows,Don't go outside
1   Sunny           bysicle ride,go outside,Play
```

Any ideas:

Comment: Is it on purpose that `Stay home1` and `Stay home` are different (same with `Go outside`). What are the rules for aggregation? Can we use `Score` as grouper?

Comment: oups Stay home1 was by mistake. I change it to Stay home

Comment: OK, and what if there are duplicated terms in Topic, do you only want to keep the unique ones?

Comment: No it is ok to have duplicated values

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
(df1.groupby(['Parent', 'Score'], sort=False)
    .apply(lambda g: g['Child'].iloc[:1].to_list()+g['Topic'].to_list())
    .reset_index(name='list1')
)
```

output:

```
       Parent Score                                              list1
0   Stay home  0.58  [Severe weather, Stay home, Close windows, Don...
1  Go outside  0.41            [Sunny, bysicle ride, go outside, Play]
```

Comment: yeah thanks. However the output is not as the expected one. The score should be after list (ok it is not a big deal) and the words inside the list to have quotes